# Float left is blocked and not aligned to left

Tags: html, css, css-float, dhtml

Consider the code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  
  <style>
     #block0 {
      width:400px
     }

     #block1, #block2, #block3 {
       float: left;
       display:inline;
     }

     #block1 {
        background-color:red;
        width:48%;
        height:200px;
      }

      #block2 {
        background-color:blue;
        width:48%;
        height:120px;
      }

      #block3 {
        background-color:green;
        width:48%;
        height:140px;
      }

  </style>

  </head>
  <body>

      <div id="block0">
          <div id="block1"></div>

          <div id="block2"></div>

          <div id="block3"></div>
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

How to make the `block3(green)` block align to the left and make it under the `block1(red)` block, and with the limitations:

1. without adding extra HTML markup
2. if need to apply new css, need to apply to all blocks

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/L4VWq/

**Update: limitations**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a clear: left to the css for block3

```
  #block3 {
    background-color:green;
    width:48%;
    height:140px;
    clear: left;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I forgot the add the limitation and now I update the question.

Comment: i don't understand why you need to change the css for all of the blocks when the issue you're having is only with one?

Comment: @Mike, it is quite possible he is in the same situation as me. That is, I am generating these div's via server side code, and thus I need a solution that fixes the issue globally as I cannot know which div, client side, will be the issue in order to specifically apply a single div solution. In that case, Matt's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
 #block1, #block2, #block3 {
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
 }
```

(no `float`)

To fight the space left from the markup you can also add a negative right margin as outlined here: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

Simply add clear:both; to #block3

See the revised fiddle.

(http://jsfiddle.net/tech0925/L4VWq/1/)